# empty commit with Repo.commit()

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm trying to do something like `repo.git.commit('-m', 'test commit', author='sunilt@xxx.com')` but instead of the  `author`,  I want to pass the `--allow-empty` to send a dummy commit to the repo. but the `repo.git.commit()` complains about the number of arguments I'm trying to pass. This is what I have so far:

```
from git import Repo
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

full_local_path = os.getenv('full_local_path')
username = os.getenv('username')
password = os.getenv('password')

remote = f"https://{username}:{password}@github.com:myRepo/myRepo.git"
Repo.clone_from('git@github.com:myRepo/myRepo.git', full_local_path)
Repo.git.commit('-m', 'empty commit', author='xxxxxxxxx')`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value from `Repo.clone_from`, which is the `Repo` object on which you'll operate in subsequent commands. You want something like:

```
>>> from git import Repo
>>> r = Repo.clone_from('https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World', 'hello-world')
>>> r.git.commit('-m', 'empty commit', '--allow-empty')
'[master 8d7508e] empty commit'
```